# Set class property in c#

Tags: c#

I have this structure:

```
public class StudentNew
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
   ...
}

public class RootObjectNew
{
    public List<StudentNew> StudentsNew { get; set; }
    public int test { get; set; }
}
```

and I want to set properties to StudentsNew.

```
RootObjectNew RootObjectNewObject = new RootObjectNew();
RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(Out);
int i = -1;
foreach (var stu in obj.Students)
{   
    i++;
    RootObjectNewObject.StudentsNew[i].StudentId = stu.Id;
    RootObjectNewObject.test = 123;
}
```

but get error:

```
2018-03-03T09:18:55.628 [Info] Compilation succeeded.
2018-03-03T09:18:56.971 [Info] C#************************
2018-03-03T09:18:57.386 [Error] Exception while executing function: Functions.fGetStudentBySkudId. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: One or
more errors occurred. f-fGetStudentBySkudId__-2136340708: Object
reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

If I comment

```
RootObjectNewObject.StudentsNew[i].StudentId = stu.Id;
```

I get status = 200
what am I doing wrong???

Comment: Please see the duplicate. In short: you're not instantiating the StudentsNew list, you're not adding any instances of student to that list, so trying to call `RootObjectNewObject.StudentsNew` will throw this exception and `RootObjectNewObject.StudentsNew[i]` would throw `IndexOutOfRangeException` even if you created a new instance for the list.

Comment: I suggest that you add a break point and step through the code.  The error message states that you have a null reference.  The debugger will show you which line fails.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong in my previous comment. I meant `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`, not `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: Don't use `foreach` if you are going to use the index anyway. Just use `for`. Though in this case you shouldn't even need it; you need to  _add_ elements.

Answer (score 2):

You must create instance of StudentNew in RootObjectNewObject:

```
RootObjectNew RootObjectNewObject = new RootObjectNew();
RootObjectNewObject.StudentsNew = new List<StudentNew>();
RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(Out);
foreach (var stu in obj.Students)
{   
    var st = new StudentNew{
      StudentId=Stu.Id,
      ...
    };
    RootObjectNewObject.StudentsNew.Add(st);

}
```

Comment: Probably needs to initialise the list object too

Comment: You are Right ...